# Is there any way to identify that my bot is added to conversation/contact list?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to give intro for my BOT . when the user is added to their conversation/contact list. I have tried by handling ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate message type. but it is not working in skype. is there any common way for this that should work in all channels.

this is the code i used:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {

            // calculate something for us to return
            int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

            // return our reply to the user
            Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }
        else if(activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
            BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);

            if (!userData.GetProperty<bool>("SentGreeting"))
            {
                Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"Hi " + activity.From.Name + ", I'm the Microsoft Bot");
                userData.SetProperty<bool>("SentGreeting", true);
                await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

[works here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvj4p.png)
thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant help with your problem, but others might if you elaborate a bit more on how you try to do it

Comment: @gismo added code now. this works for emulator and web chat . not working in skype. any suggestions?

Comment: Do you receive the ConversationUpdate event?

Comment: no. for skype. I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Skype` channel doesn't send the `ConversationUpdate` message. The `Bot Framework Emulator` and other channels like `WebChat` do. There isn't a way to send a message to the user before receiving a message from the user in the `Skype` channel.